# Asp.net MVC4 Multiple Models 1 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So im writing an application that has an upload Area for images..

What I would like to do is Dynamicallyi build a path for files that are to be uploaded.

The User would select a Client,Market,Project and Place ( all of these are Seperate Models )

I would like to build a View that Showed Clients( dropdown), Market (dropdown) and so on so i can then grab those values to place them on the Server under a directory in that name...

I do not know how to combine my models to get them all into a Single view, other then creating a partial view for every dropdown menu ( is this the right way to handle this ? )

Can anyone Help? - Thanks

EDITS :

Here is what i was thinking you ment i could throw into a Razor View ( givin i pass all of them somehow )

```
@model OilNGasWeb.Models.UserProfiles
@model OilNGasWeb.Models.UserInfo
@model OilNGasWeb.Models.UserData
@model OilNGasWeb.Models.Users
```

then some code beneath ... thats what you ment with Hierarchie?

---

what i was thinking is to include the IEnumerable<> in the model of say the Main Model Was Users

> User Model

```
[Table("Users")]
public class UserProfiles
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> UsersRoless { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserInfo> UsersInfos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserData> UsersDatas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Users> Userss { get; set; }
```

then do partial views for each in the index view of Users...

Trying to think of a better concept ( if there is one ) sorry for making the question unclear

Comment: A model can be hierarchical, so why not add those other models as properties of the root view model?

Comment: @BrianMains What do you mean , like in the view : @ model og.UserProfiles and then next line like @ model og.UserRoles and then @ model og.UserInfo?????

Comment: Yes, possibly...  Could you include some code to help us see what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining, this is all trying to find the best concept, nothing is written yet. I would like to find / think about the best way to code before coding. look above edits for what i was trying to say in the coment above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have many models like that, but you can do:

```
public class RootModel
{
  public Ienumerable<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }

  public UserInfo User { get; set; }

  public Ienumerable<User> Users { get; set; }

  .
  .
}
```

And then pass this to your complex view.  You can pass the data to partial views by supplying the model property of the `Html.Partial("X", Model)` form of the method.

Comment: Alright thanks, I was jsut curious if there was a better way of doing this. Thanks for the response. Also on an unrelated side, if you don't mind, Can i use the same princible and the entity framework will know where to store what data ( say i use this concept for an edit? )

Comment: As long as all the data comes from the same context, you can then use it for an edit.  However, the object context lives only for the current request (unless you store it as a static, but then you have other problems) so it depends what you mean.  You can use the same principal, but if you load an edit form, then render, then save the change, this can be a little more complicated and requires some "care".  The best thing I can say is give it a shot, and write another question if it doesn't work :)  It's always a good learning experience.